# Issue with aligning divs vertically

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to make multiple divs inside a div vertically aligned. They should start at the top and have space in between evenly.

This works for me but the child-divs are starting at the top-left side of the parent div (see first picture):

```
 <div className="flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen w-full">
                    <div>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Game Code' onChange={(event) => setRoomCode(event.target.value)} />
                        <button className="text-white ml-3" type="submit" onClick={handleEnterCode}>JOIN GAME</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 className="text-white">OR</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button className="text-white" type="submit" onClick={e => setShowForm(true)}>CREATE GAME</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={handleLogout}>
                            <button className="text-white" type="submit">logout</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I use "flex" - the problem is - that it places my child-divs very far at the bottom. (See in the second picture).

[First picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UTCL.png)

```
 <div className="flex-col flex items-center justify-center h-screen w-full">
                    <div>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Game Code' onChange={(event) => setRoomCode(event.target.value)} />
                        <button className="text-white ml-3" type="submit" onClick={handleEnterCode}>JOIN GAME</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 className="text-white">OR</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button className="text-white" type="submit" onClick={e => setShowForm(true)}>CREATE GAME</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={handleLogout}>
                            <button className="text-white" type="submit">logout</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[Second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7HX2.png)

Comment: Can you post your css and the image with the desired outcome? That could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a parent container class with the following properties.

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container" className="flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen w-full">
<div>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Game Code' />
    <button className="text-white ml-3" type="submit" onClick={handleEnterCode}>JOIN GAME</button>
</div>
<div>
    <h1 className="text-white">OR</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <button className="text-white" type="submit">CREATE GAME</button>
</div>
<div>
    <form onSubmit={handleLogout}>
        <button className="text-white" type="submit">logout</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Maybe you could accept the answer as the solution? :)

Comment: Yes of course, thanks again :-) (sorry I am new to stackOverflow :-) )

Answer (score 0):

My desired outcome would be:

```
-------------------------
|          div          |
|                       |
|          div          |
|                       |
|          div          |
-------------------------
```

I don't use CSS files as I am using tailwind:

It looks like this currently

```
<div className="flex-col flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full">
                    <div>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Game Code' onChange={(event) => setRoomCode(event.target.value)} />
                        <button className="text-white ml-3" type="submit" onClick={handleEnterCode}>JOIN GAME</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 className="text-white">OR</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button className="text-white" type="submit" onClick={e => setShowForm(true)}>CREATE GAME</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={handleLogout}>
                            <button className="text-white" type="submit">logout</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

... leading into this result:

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEsDb.png)

Comment: Added the solution as an answer. Hope that helps.